# Use intermediate value theorem to prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}} = 2^x -8$ has a solution

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}} = 2^x -8$ has a solution using the IVT, not so sure how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x):=LHS-RHS$ and find two values of $x$ giving opposite signs.

Comment: TheGreatDuck:  you didn't?  If x > 5 then both sides are continuous.  At x = 6 left hand side is less than the right hand side.  But lim x -> 5 LHS goes to infinity while right hand side decreases toward 24.  By IVT there's a point between 5 and 6 that they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. For $x>5$, consider the continuous function,
$$f(x)=2^x - 8-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}.$$
Note that $f(6)=2^6-8-1=55>0$.

Now the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to 5^+$ is $-\infty$ and, by the definition of limit, there is $5<x_0<6$ such that $f(x_0)<0$ (you don't have to find it explicitly).

Therefore by IVT, $f$ has a zero in the interval $(x_0,6)\subset (5,6)$.

Comment: @Vikram Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Look at $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}} - 2^x + 8$.

We know $f(5.00001)=292.227$, $f(6)=-55$, what can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}} - 2^x + 8$ on the domain $(5,\infty)$.

Now evaluate the function $f(x)$ at some $x$ very close to $5$, but greater than $5$. The function should have a positive value. In fact you can use that:

$$\lim_{x \to 5^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 5^{+}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}} - 2^x + 8 = \infty$$

Then on the otherside evaluate $f(x)$ at $9$ to get that $f(9) = -503.5$. So by the IVT as the function $f$ is continuous we have a zero somewhere on the interval $(5,9)$